# How can I force the order of axis labels?

Tags: kibana

I have data with a label `priority` that I show on a heatmap:

[image]

The order at the bottom is not the one I would like to have (which is `CRITICAL`, `HIGH`, ...)

**How can I instruct Kibana to use a specific order for the labels?** I went through all the options and there is no hint of that possibility, but then maybe there is a more advanced way to control such details?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [Nick Peihl](https://discuss.elastic.co/u/nickpeihl/summary) from the Elastic Forum I have [the solution](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-can-i-force-the-order-of-labels/327424/2?u=wpq)

> If you are using Lens, try changing from `Top Values` to `Filters`. Then specify the order you'd like to arrange the buckets in the access.